# How to run a 2008 SSIS package from a win froms app on a user machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

i've written a small c# 4.0 winforms app to get some input from the user and then pass this as a parameter to a SSIS package and then run the package.

I use the following code and it works fine on my development machine when I'm accessing the package on the production server.

```
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
        Package createInvoice = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\MyPackage", "MyProducitonServer",
            null, null, null);
        createInvoice.Variables["PeriodID"].Value = _selectedPeriodId;
        DTSExecResult result = createInvoice.Execute();
```

However when I deploy the app to a users machine using a standard setup msi the app throws an error infomring me that it can't find an Integration Service Class and that the IS Server is not installed don the machine.

Can I run a package from the suers machine or do I have to schedule a job on sql agent to run the package for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSIS Runtime is not a standalone package - it is packaged with Standard, Developer or Enterprise. If the client machine does not have SQL Server installed you cannot run the package on the client machine.

See [here](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-ssis/1025/SSIS-Runtime-distribution) for a discussion.

Comment: Is there a best practice for running a SISS package using c#? Create a job? Through T-SQL comands?